# Not able to get desired output while working with PartioningBy and groupingBy together

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, partitioning, collectors

I am working with collectors' groupingBy and partioningBy functions. I an working with a list of persons, the list of persons is as follows:

```
List<Person> persons =
        Arrays.asList(
            new Person("Max", 18),
            new Person("Peter", 23),
            new Person("Pamela", 23),
            new Person("David", 12),
            new Person("Pam", 12));
```

What i want is to partition the list on the basis of persons whose name starts with letter "P" and then group them on the basis of their ages.
Here is my code which does the above filtration:

```
Map<Boolean, Map<Object, List<Person>>> rr = persons.stream()
                                            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(p -> p.name.startsWith("P"), 
                                                    Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.age > 20)));
```

And the output which i got is:

```
rr = {false={false=[Max, David]}, true={false=[Pam], true=[Peter, Pamela]}}
```

Now, my requirement is to get only internal map from the above results. That is, i want to change the return values to:

```
{false=[Pam], true=[Peter, Pamela]}
```

That is, I want the results (or partitioned map) whose boolean value is true as returned by the partioningBy function. How can i achieve this?

Comment: *Why* do you want this? Just do a `filter(p -> p.name.startsWith("P"))` *before* `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.age > 20))`. Otherwise, if you like to collect data that you don’t use afterwards, just do as posted in your question and call `get(true)` on the result.

Comment: Not specific for the reason. Just looking out if there is any way with this particular scenario.

Comment: Well, you can filter before or extract afterwards. Both is simple. What else do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom collector (I've done it only as an exercise, please treat it as such):

```
 static class MyCustom<T, U> implements Collector<Person, List<Person>, Map<T, List<U>>> {

    private final Function<Person, T> function;

    private final Predicate<Person> predicate;

    private final Function<Person, U> transformingFunction;

    public MyCustom(Predicate<Person> predicate, Function<Person, T> function,
            Function<Person, U> transformingFunction) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
        this.function = function;
        this.transformingFunction = transformingFunction;
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<List<Person>> supplier() {
        return ArrayList::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<List<Person>, Person> accumulator() {
        return (list, person) -> {
            if (predicate.test(person)) {
                list.add(person);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<List<Person>> combiner() {
        return (l1, l2) -> {
            l1.addAll(l2);
            return l1;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<List<Person>, Map<T, List<U>>> finisher() {
        return list -> {
            return list.stream().collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(function, Collectors.mapping(transformingFunction, Collectors.toList())));
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Set<java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return EnumSet.of(Characteristics.UNORDERED);
    }
}
```

And then apply it like this:

```
 MyCustom<Integer, String> custom = new MyCustom<>((Person p) -> p.getName().startsWith("P"),
            (Person p) -> p.getAge(), Person::getName);

 System.out.println(persons.stream().collect(custom)); // {23=[Peter, Pamela], 12=[Pam]}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Filter by `name`
2. Apply partitioning by `age`

   ```
       Map<Boolean, List<Person>> p1 = persons.stream().filter(p -> p.name.startsWith("P")).collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(p -> p.getAge() > 20));
   ```